# Java JComboBox.setSelectedItem() not updating dropdown list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, selecteditem

I want to make function updating current item in `JComboBox`:

```
@Override
public void updateId(String id) {
    boolean old = notify;
    notify = false;
    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(id);
    comboBox.setEditable(false);
    notify = old;
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

1. ComboBox is bound to textbox,
2. I change textbox value, which is calling updateId(),
3. Expanding combobox,
4. Selecting item that got changed,

The combo's drop down list does not reflect the change made to selected item; in the given example, there should be "xxx" at the bottom of drop down list.

Comment: How are you adding the new string to the comboBox?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @Override
 public void add(String id) {
  comboBox.addItem(id);
 }

Comment: Please write your solution as a proper answer and accept it so the question is marked as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misinterpreted `JComboBox.setSelectedItem()`.

It sounds like it should override item being under selected index of model when combobox is editable, but it just overrides displayed value and doesn't touch model.

This one does the job:

```
    @Override
    public void updateId(String id) {
        boolean old = notify;
        notify = false;
        comboBox.setEditable(true);

        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel();
        int selectedIndex = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
        model.removeElementAt(selectedIndex);
        model.insertElementAt(id, selectedIndex);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);

        comboBox.setEditable(false);
        notify = old;
    }
```